# Consuming HATEOAS Resource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I have a simple **HATEOAS** provider built with **Spring** that provides me with the resource below:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employees{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employees/search"
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "employees" : [ {
      "id" : "5400d5152f5243f1988c649b",
      "name" : "Some Employee",
      "location" : [ 0.0, 0.0 ],
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employees/5400d5152f5243f1988c649b"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "id" : "5400d5162f5243f1988c649c",
      "name" : "Some Employee",
      "location" : [ 0.0, 0.0 ],
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employees/5400d5162f5243f1988c649c"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "id" : "5400d5172f5243f1988c649d",
      "name" : "Some Employee",
      "location" : [ 0.0, 0.0 ],
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employees/5400d5172f5243f1988c649d"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 3,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

In a separate Spring client, I attempt to consume this resource with no avail:

```
@RequestMapping("/employees")
public String getAllEmployees() {

    try {
        ResponseEntity<Resource> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(RESOURCE_URI, Resource.class);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Jackson 2.0 goes on to complain:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "page" (class org.springframework.hateoas.Resource), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "content", "links"])
 at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@743a4ace; line: 19, column: 13] (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.Resource["page"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "page" (class org.springframework.hateoas.Resource), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "content", "links"])
 at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@743a4ace; line: 19, column: 13] (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.Resource["page"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:216)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:784)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:769)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:502)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:264)
    at com.provider.spring.controller.EmployeeController.getAllEmployees(EmployeeController.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "page" (class org.springframework.hateoas.Resource), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "content", "links"])
 at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@743a4ace; line: 19, column: 13] (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.Resource["page"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:51)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:731)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:915)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1298)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1276)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:243)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:118)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3051)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2206)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:213)
    ... 44 more
Sep 05, 2014 3:54:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
WARNING: Servlet jsp is currently unavailable
```

And for calrity, this is my Resource object:
https://gist.github.com/Xerosigma/02041fdc0849a651dcbf

### What am I missing?

Comment: From the looks of it, it's mapping links and content just fine but blows up when it see page. I've tried adding this to my Resource object but still no cigar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems like your class `Resource` do not have a field named `page` so the parser can not handle this json object :

```
"page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 3,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
}
```

You can try with :

```
public class Page {

    private int size;

    private int totalElements;

    private int totalPages;

    private int number;

    // Getters and Setters...
}
```

and in your class `Resource` :

```
public class Resource<T> extends ResourceSupport {

    private final T content;

    private Page page;

    ...
}
```

Comment: You were spot on. Problem was I was referencing Springs Resource object instead of mine.

Answer (score 2):

The default jackson mapper is configured to fail on unrecognised fields on json objects. You need to configure the mapper with `mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`

Here's an example Spring config:

```java
package com.pkg.mine;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector;
import org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.pkg.mine")
public class ServerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        //We handle both incoming JSON, and XML
        final AnnotationIntrospector jsonInspector = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
        final AnnotationIntrospector xmlInspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
        final AnnotationIntrospector pair = 
              new AnnotationIntrospector.Pair(jsonInspector, xmlInspector);

        final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        //Don't fail if additional fields in incoming JSON, just ignore
        om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        //Don't fail on incoming JSON missing fields
        om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false);
        om.setAnnotationIntrospector(pair);

        final MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter converter = 
                new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(om);
        converters.add(converter);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a read in the mean time. Thank you for your time.

Comment: OK, on more research, you can also annotate your receiving class with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`. Using the annotation will apply the behaviour purely for unmarshalling of that object type. Configuring the mapper as described above is an across the board decision (i.e. all unmarshalling using this mapper will now ignore missing fields).

Comment: These are some nice options for controlling the marshaller. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: I gather this decision to ignore the HATEOAS links of the json payload is because they are never needed in the resources objects ?

Answer (score 1):

Use

> ```
>     ResponseEntity<PagedResources<EmployeeResource>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("URI", HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedResources<EmployeeResource>>(){});
> ```

where EmployeeResource is a resource class . To get employees

> responseEntity.getBody().getContent

The above snippet will return a Collection of EmployeeResource